# How to generate a closed surface using sverchok?

Tags: sverchok

I just learned how to create a surface from a number of circles with different radii:

[image]

the problem with this though is that the shape has a hole at the top and bottom (although the radius is 0 at both points). that's why when applying a subsurf modifier creates this kind of unwanted result:

[image]

so my question is: using only sverchok, is there a way to close these holes?

Comment: Also, you can close the ends by enabling "Cup U" or "Cup V", (it's a mis-spelling of "cap"). This will however produce a face without area because the ends are made my verts with identical locations. Not useful in this location, but normally that's what you'd do to "make the surface closed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Please, use cap U/V button to close mesh instead of both cycle U/V
Use help there nikitron.cc.ua/sverch/html/nodes/modifier_make/uv_connect.html

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that you have an internal vertex/circle of vertices on the top. Can you check the topology before subsurf?

[image]
[image]

You can see on the second picture that there is one circle with 0 radius inside on this reproduction of your problem.

Then, I dont know sverchok but i guess it should do the trick:

[sverch Remove Doubles](http://nikitron.cc.ua/sverch/html/nodes/modifier_change/remove_doubles.html)

Comment: Remove Doubles will not be merge the desired vertices in their mean location (sadly) it might however just merge them in 1 of the original locations. https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/619340/27597495-c9c10b7c-5b62-11e7-848e-4c9b3d29f221.png -- if those vertices share the same 3d location, this effect will be unnoticed.